# Why do I get the error of unable to cast object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following GridView:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDropDown" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="pnlDropDown">
    <!-- TASK NAME -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- SERVICE -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- STATUS -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateStatus" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Status" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- DUE DATE -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDueDate" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDueDate" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Due Date" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDueDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- OWNER -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwner" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateOwner" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Owner" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateOwner" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- CLIENT -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateClient" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Client" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateClient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- SITE -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateSite" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Site" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSite_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateSite" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- PRACTICE -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPractice" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulatePractice" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Practice" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPractice_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulatePractice" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!-- PROVIDER -->
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvider" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateProvider" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Provider" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProvider_onSelectIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateProvider" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Label ID="lblDDLBlank" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDep" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Dependencies"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Dependencies" ID="btnShowDepend" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") %>' />                
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" SortExpression="Site" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Practice" HeaderText="Practice" SortExpression="Practice" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" SortExpression="Provider" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The following function which populates the GridView:

```
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir, bool blOnLoad)
{
    query = "";
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    connString = @"";

    if (!blOnLoad)
    {
        //SET UP THE "query" QUERY STRING
    }
    else
    {
        //SET UP THE "query" QUERY STRING
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

protected void yourTasksGV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView hGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);


        TableHeaderCell tcCellTask = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellTask.Controls.Add(ddlTaskName);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellTask);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellDep = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellDep.Controls.Add(lblDDLBlank);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellDep);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellSvc = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellSvc.Controls.Add(ddlService);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellSvc);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellStats = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellStats.Controls.Add(ddlStatus);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellStats);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellDD = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellDD.Controls.Add(ddlDueDate);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellDD);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellOwner = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellOwner.Controls.Add(ddlOwner);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellOwner);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellCli = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellCli.Controls.Add(ddlClient);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellCli);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellSit = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellSit.Controls.Add(ddlSite);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellSit);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellPra = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellPra.Controls.Add(ddlPractice);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellPra);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellPro = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellPro.Controls.Add(ddlProvider);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellPro);

        yourTasksGV.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvrRow);

        LinkButton btnSort;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image;
        //iterate through all the header cells
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            //check if the header cell has any child controls
            if (cell.HasControls())
            {
                //get reference to the button column
                btnSort = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
                image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                if (ViewState["sortExp"] != null)
                {
                    //see if the button user clicked on and the sortexpression in the viewstate are same
                    //this check is needed to figure out whether to add the image to this heade column or not
                    if (btnSort.CommandArgument == ViewState["sortExp"].ToString())
                    {
                        //check what type of sort order it is
                        if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "Asc")
                        {
                            image.ImageUrl = "../theImages/up.png";
                            image.CssClass = "hdrImage";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            image.ImageUrl = "../theImages/down.png";
                            image.CssClass = "hdrImage";
                        }
                        cell.Controls.Add(image);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the web application, the RowCreated is iterated and then it gives me the following error:

```
unable to cast object of type 'system.web.ui.literalcontrol' to type 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton'
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Put a breakpoint, get aha-moment. Obviously `cell.Controls[0]` is _not_ a `LinkButton`, just like the exception states.

Comment: I don't want that cell to have the ability to sort.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: All the column Header text is a link which allows me to click and sort. That second column, "Dependencies" doesn't have to allow the user to sort. It can just be a plain header text and fill it with the OBJECT commandargument from the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably this line :

```
btnSort = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
```

The first control in your cell is most probably a Litteral (although I see an "HyperlinkField"), which you're trying to Cast to a linkButton, thus throwing this error.

Comment: That works fine for me, until I have added the `<asp:TemplateField>` section and now it is giving me an error.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? The exception message is quite explicit about the problem, and this is the only line I see with a casting attempt to linkbutton so I'm quite sure this is the line causing trouble, maybe not for the reason I state as such though...

Comment: Yes i debugged it and went through the code but the HyperlinkField didn't give the error.

Comment: ...do a proper casting obviously ! cfr answer from user1429080. But if you went through debug mode and nothing failed, this is some kind of magic...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely the fact that in one header cell you are adding a `Label`:

```
TableHeaderCell tcCellDep = new TableHeaderCell();
tcCellDep.Controls.Add(lblDDLBlank);
gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellDep);
```

When going through the header cells later on you try to cast this `Label` as a `LinkButton` which is not possible.

To fix it, check that it really is a `LinkButton`:

```
if (cell.HasControls())
{
    //get reference to the button column
    btnSort = cell.Controls[0] as LinkButton;
    image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    if (ViewState["sortExp"] != null && btnSort != null)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```